# How do I make an mp3 downloadable from podbean without it opening in the browser?

Tags: html, audio, download

I'm trying to make a podcast episode downloadable but it just opens in the browser. Tested with Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

I've tried using a link with the download attribute but that didn't work.

`<a download href="https://mcdn.podbean.com/mf/web/wvdg4n/Get_Out_of_The_Rut_.mp3">Download</a>`

I'd prefer to use just html but I'm open to any secure solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worked for me.

```
<a download href="https://mcdn.podbean.com/mf/web/wvdg4n/Get_Out_of_The_Rut_.mp3" id="downloadapp-1">Download</a>
```

If you have a lot of mp3 files, you need to implement click function in a Javascript file and load it on header, like this:

```
$("a[id^=downloadapp").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
    window.location.href = this.href;
});
```

With the second, third, ... mp3 files, you need to change the id respectively (downloadapp-"number").